# iOS Swift: "No such module 'Firebase'", can't use Firebase even though package is installed

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, tuist

Project uses Tuist and Swift Dependancy Package Manager, Firebase is installed yet I can't import it into files without errors. Existing files that already have it imported don't get such errors. Why am I getting this error? I have tried deleting DerivedData, reinstalling the project, dependencies, clean etc.

[image: Package firebase]

Comment: The Firebase module added to the target that the source file belongs to?

Comment: All dependencies installed using Tuist command, so not sure what I should be checking.

Comment: you can start by checking if the firebase module is present in this target's dependencies in `Project.swift`

Comment: That helps me see what the issue is, thanks. I'm trying to use Firebase in a UITestTarget, can't import it to that. But I can't use function from file in main target at so still at a loss for now.